# Gracefully (i.e eventually cooperatively) suspend thread execution

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I have to develop an application that tries to emulate the executing flow of an embedded target. This target has 2 levels of priority : the highest one being preemptive on the lowest one. The low priority level is managed with a round-robin scheduler which gives 1ms of execution to each thread in turn.

My goal is to write a library that provide the thread_create, thread_start, and all the system calls that are available on my target and use POSIX functions to reproduce the behavior natively on a standard PC.
Thus, when an high priority thread executes, low priority threads should be suspended whatever they are doing at that very moment. It is to the responsibility of the low priority thread's implementation to ensure that it won't be perturbed.

I now it is usually unsafe to suspend a thread, which explains why I didn't find any "suspend(pid)" function.

I basically imagine two solutions to the problem :
-find a way to suspend the low priority threads when a high priority thread starts (and resume them when there is no more high priority activity)
-periodically call a very small "suspend_if_necessary" function everywhere in my low-priority code, and whenever an high priority must start, wait for all low-priority process to call that function and be suspended, execute as single high priority thread, then resume them all.

Even if it is not-so-clean, I quite like the second solution, but still have one problem : how to call the function everywhere without changing all my code?
I wonder if there is an easy way to doing that, somewhat like debugging code does : add a hook call at every line executed that checks for a flag and run some specific code when that flag changes?

I'd be very happy if there is an easy solution to that problem, since I really need to be representative with the behavior of the target execution flow...

Thanks in advance,

Goulou.

Comment: By the way, the high prio thread can be started by 3 sources only : launched by a low prio thread, an external interruption, or after after a sleep. All of these sources reside inside my library, so I am "aware" of it and can send any message to the other threads immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not really possible to implement what you want with true threads - even if the high prio thread is restarted, it can take arbitrarily long before the high prio thread is scheduled back in and goes to suspend all the low priority threads. Moreover, there is no reliable way to determine whether the high priority thread is blocked or not using only POSIX threads; you could try tracking things manually, but this runs the risk of both false positives (the thread's blocked on something, but the low prio threads think it's running and suspend itself) and false negatives (you miss a resumed annotation, or there's lag between when the thread's actually resumed and when it marks itself as running).

If you want to implement a thread priority system with pure POSIX, one option is to *not* use threads, but rather use [setcontext](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setcontext) for cooperative multitasking. This would allow you to swap between threads at a user level. However you must explicitly yield the CPU in this case. It also doesn't help with blocking syscalls, which would then block all threads in your app; but since you're writing an emulator this might not be an issue.

You *may* also be able to swap threads using setcontext within a signal handler; I've not tested this case myself, but it could be worth a try scheduling using setcontext in a SIGALRM handler.

Comment: About your first point : in my idea, the high priority thread would wait on a lock (semaphore) until all the other active threads (I can count them) are actually suspended. The only thing missing is to make all the other threads call this "suspend_if_necessary" function.  
On the other end, the high and low prio thread can only be blocked on something inside my library (event, pipe read...), so this is what I consider as internaly controlled (I now which thread is active, suspended...)

Answer (score 0):

To suspend a thread, you sleep it.  If you want to be able to wake it on command, sleep it using [sigwait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sigwait), which puts the thread to sleep until it gets a signal.  You can send a specific thread a signal with [pthread_kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_kill) (crazy name, but it actually just sends signals to a thread).  This is a very fast way to sleep and wake up threads.  40x Faster than condition variables and very easy.